# Jquery selectors work only for the first time in the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

My objective is to select the last option of all drop down boxes in a page (Every thing goes right but when I try to run my code second time the results do not change)I tried to log the jquery selector code but didn't understand the result I don't know why does my code works for the first time only.Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("select option:last-child").attr("selected", "selected"); //Select the last drop down list option of each drop down list.
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("Done!");
    }, 10)
  });
});
```

```css
//Style of my button.
.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  background-color: #007dc1;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #124d77;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.myButton:hover {
  background-color: #0061a7;
}

.myButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <select>
      <option id="a1" value="cars">Select Car</option>
      <option id="a2" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option id="a3" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option id="a4" value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <select>
      <option id="b1" value="nationality">Select Nationality</option>
      <option id="b2" value="lebanese">Lebanese</option>
      <option id="b3" value="chinese">Chinese</option>
      <option id="b4" value="egyption">Egyption</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <select>
      <option id="c1" value="color">Select Color</option>
      <option id="c2" value="red">Red</option>
      <option id="c3" value="yellow">Yellow</option>
      <option id="c4" value="green">Green</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <select>
      <option id="d1" value="computers">Select Computer</option>
      <option id="d2" value="hp">Hp</option>
      <option id="d3" value="acer">Acer</option>
      <option id="d4" value="toshiba">Toshiba</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <button id="btn1" class="myButton">Select Last Value</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This code just gives me the results for the first time but after the second time    something goes wrong.What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting an attribute for the option, but I guess you should change the `<select>` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    //Select the last drop down list option of each drop down list.
    $("select").each(function() {
      this.selectedIndex = this.length - 1;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
//Style of my button.
.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  background-color: #007dc1;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #124d77;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.myButton:hover {
  background-color: #0061a7;
}

.myButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <select>
      <option id="a1" value="cars">Select Car</option>
      <option id="a2" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option id="a3" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option id="a4" value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <select>
      <option id="b1" value="nationality">Select Nationality</option>
      <option id="b2" value="lebanese">Lebanese</option>
      <option id="b3" value="chinese">Chinese</option>
      <option id="b4" value="egyption">Egyption</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <select>
      <option id="c1" value="color">Select Color</option>
      <option id="c2" value="red">Red</option>
      <option id="c3" value="yellow">Yellow</option>
      <option id="c4" value="green">Green</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <select>
      <option id="d1" value="computers">Select Computer</option>
      <option id="d2" value="hp">Hp</option>
      <option id="d3" value="acer">Acer</option>
      <option id="d4" value="toshiba">Toshiba</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <button id="btn1" class="myButton">Select Last Value</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the attr of the dropdown so your code can run with out breaking the drops.

You can acomplish with the next line.

```
$("select option").removeAttr("selected");
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("select option").removeAttr("selected");
    $("select option:last-child").attr("selected", "selected"); //Select the last drop down list option of each drop down list.
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("Done!");
    }, 10)
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    //Style of my button.
    .myButton {
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
      background-color: #007dc1;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #124d77;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 10px 9px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .myButton:hover {
      background-color: #0061a7;
    }
    
    .myButton:active {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <select>
        <option id="a1" value="cars">Select Car</option>
        <option id="a2" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option id="a3" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option id="a4" value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <select>
        <option id="b1" value="nationality">Select Nationality</option>
        <option id="b2" value="lebanese">Lebanese</option>
        <option id="b3" value="chinese">Chinese</option>
        <option id="b4" value="egyption">Egyption</option>
      </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <select>
        <option id="c1" value="color">Select Color</option>
        <option id="c2" value="red">Red</option>
        <option id="c3" value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option id="c4" value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <select>
        <option id="d1" value="computers">Select Computer</option>
        <option id="d2" value="hp">Hp</option>
        <option id="d3" value="acer">Acer</option>
        <option id="d4" value="toshiba">Toshiba</option>
      </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <button id="btn1" class="myButton">Select Last Value</button>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you rerun your code, the last option already has the attr selected. So in a qay the code skips it and that why you doent see the last option as the result. But if you inspect the code, you will see it has the attr selected. Once you reset all of the attrs. It will execute the change at the DOM